# Connect to OLED Display Module

Tags: display, screen

I would like to connect to the following display which I've purchased:
http://www.buydisplay.com/default/serial-3-2-inch-display-arduino-256x64-oled-screen-module-white-on-black#wishlist-wrapper
This uses an SSD1322 display driver.

I have some very noob questions:

- How do I connect the display to the raspberry pi?
- What software or drivers do I need to install?

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a trivial project.

That display cannot be directly connected to the Raspberry Pi.  You will need to build something to connect the 30 pin flex connector to the right pins on the GPIO connector.

According to [the manual](http://www.buydisplay.com/download/ic/SSD1322.pdf) the display supports 4-pin SPI (see page 19) so you can use that to drive the display. You will also need a separate power supply for the display since it needs 10-20V for the panel.

It looks like there is a [project on github](https://github.com/presslab-us/fbtft) to make a kernel module that supports that display.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OLED display that is already mounted. Something like this:

[image: OLED Module]

These come is SPI and I2C flavors. You can then connect the module to your Pi and enable I2C or SPI depending on your module on Raspberry Pi.

You would have to write your own code to initialize and use the OLED module. It is not that difficult as I have used them with PIC microcontroller.